# NoSuchMethodError JedisCommands.del(String s) when upgrade Spring Boot 3.0.1

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

I'm getting this error after upgrade Spring Boot from 2.7.3 to 3.0.1:
Here the error :

`Exception in thread "schedulerFactoryBean_QuartzSchedulerThread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Long redis.clients.jedis.commands.JedisCommands.del(java.lang.String)' at net.joelinn.quartz.jobstore.AbstractRedisStorage.unlock(AbstractRedisStorage.java:118) at net.joelinn.quartz.jobstore.RedisJobStore.doWithLock(RedisJobStore.java:1169) at net.joelinn.quartz.jobstore.RedisJobStore.acquireNextTriggers(RedisJobStore.java:1043) at org.quartz.core.QuartzSchedulerThread.run(QuartzSchedulerThread.java:287)`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHjul.png)

The error come from:
`public boolean unlock(T jedis) { String currentLock = jedis.get(this.redisSchema.lockKey()); if (!this.isNullOrEmpty(currentLock) && UUID.fromString(currentLock).equals(this.lockValue)) { jedis.del(this.redisSchema.lockKey()); return true; } else { return false; } }`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7k7pT.png)

I can start the project and run it perfectly but anytime I start my project I will see this error.

Redis-client version is 4.3.1

quartz-redis-jobstore version is 1.2.0

I tried to remove the old version and install the latest version of Redis-client and quartz-redis-jobstore but cant not resolve the problem.

Comment: it could be related to conflict between Spring Data Redis version and Jedis version. you can try different versions and find out which is compatible for that Jedis version.